# How to convert unicode into character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In some case special characters are converted into unicode like below string. how to change again into special character.

Ex:-

```
///Incoming string 
"ਸਪੋਰਟਸ ਫੈਕਟਰੀ &#8216;ਚ ਅੱਗ ਨਾਲ ਹਾਹਾਕਾਰ ,ਦੇਖੋ ਅੱਗ &#8216;ਤੇ ਕਿਵੇਂ ਪਾਇਆ ਕਾਬੂ"

///Expected output
"ਸਪੋਰਟਸ ਫੈਕਟਰੀ ‘ਚ ਅੱਗ ਨਾਲ ਹਾਹਾਕਾਰ ,ਦੇਖੋ ਅੱਗ ‘ਤੇ ਕਿਵੇਂ ਪਾਇਆ ਕਾਬੂ"
```

Comment: Make sure you have this in your html header <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: The string came from the frontend team. Is there any way to convert it into from backend side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DOMParser to convert the string.

```
function decodeHTMLEntities(text) {
  const parser = new DOMParser();
  const decodedString = parser.parseFromString(text, 'text/html').body.textContent;
  return decodedString;
}

decodeHTMLEntities("ਸਪੋਰਟਸ ਫੈਕਟਰੀ &#8216;ਚ ਅੱਗ ਨਾਲ ਹਾਹਾਕਾਰ ,ਦੇਖੋ ਅੱਗ &#8216;ਤੇ ਕਿਵੇਂ ਪਾਇਆ ਕਾਬੂ");

// Expected output
"ਸਪੋਰਟਸ ਫੈਕਟਰੀ ‘ਚ ਅੱਗ ਨਾਲ ਹਾਹਾਕਾਰ ,ਦੇਖੋ ਅੱਗ ‘ਤੇ ਕਿਵੇਂ ਪਾਇਆ ਕਾਬੂ"
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString)